# bootstrap - keep side-menu open RTL

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using this "right to left" Bootstrap admin template -

https://ampleadmin.wrappixel.com/ampleadmin-html/ampleadmin-rtl/index3.html

I would like to keep the right side-menu open all the time (like here: https://ampleadmin.wrappixel.com/ampleadmin-html/ampleadmin-sidebar/index2.html)

I didn't find where and what should I change...
I'll appreciate your help

Thanks,
Roi

Answer (score 0):

add a class mini-sidebar on your main-wrapper div

```
<div class="mini-sidebar" id="main-wrapper" data-theme="light" data-layout="vertical" data-navbarbg="skin1" data-sidebartype="full" data-sidebar-position="fixed" data-header-position="fixed" data-boxed-layout="full">
```